# Why do I get false in both cases?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to check if any two integers in array in sum equal to n. However, I get false for the first case, though I think I should get true.

```
def sum_to_n?(array, n)
  for i in array
    s = n - i
    return true if array.include? s
    return false if i != n - i
  end
end

puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 9)
puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 12)
```

Comment: Why you are using this logic `i != n - i`? I am curious to know.

Comment: I have some idea in Python, but know idea about syntax in Ruby. Actually, if I don't return false, I get all the elements in the array printed. Anyhow, according to my logic, the first test should return true, which is not the case for some reason. Some two elements of array can be equal to n, then the method should return true. I am checking, whether some n - i is contained in the array. i != n - i is incorrect, you're right.

Comment: Your method name is confusing, as you aren't getting the sum of anything in the method.  You are getting the differences, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in not so many lines :-)

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
n=9
ary.combination(2).detect { |a, b| a + b == n }
```

Comment: +1 This will handle arrays like `[1,2,3,4,4]; n=8` correctly.

Comment: @steenslag That was the point the OP was not necessarily clear, but judging from `i != n - i` in the OP's code and the phrase `if any two integers` in the question, I think that multiple occurrences of identical number should not count as satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = n - i # => 8, 11
```

`s` isn't what you think it is, then.

You get false, in the first case, because you believe that 8 or 11 is included in the arrays you give with elements from 1 to 5.  This works when you give something such as 6 or 3

Answer (score 0):

It return always `false`, because you return `false` right in the first loop. Correct would be:

```
def sum_to_n?(array, n)
  for number in array
    return true if array.include?(n - number)
  end

  false
end
```

false is returned explicitly if the loop ends without finding a match.

Comment: I don't understand that syntax... Just couple of days of learning Ruby. Could you please write it down not using array.each do |number|?  Just the way I tried to implement it?

Comment: You can write this better `array.any? { |num| array.include?(n - num) }`.

Comment: Changed the code on your wish. See the difference to your code?

Comment: @user2742080 Unless you're just passing through Ruby with no intent to stay, you'll really want to learn about Ruby's `each` iterator. It's not that hard, and it's widely used.

Answer (score 0):

How is this ?

```
def sum_to_n?(array, n)
  for i in array
    s = n - i
    return true if array.include?(s)
  end
  false # This will be retuned only when no two numbers are found,whose sum is n
end

puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 9)
puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 12)
# >> true
# >> false
```

Simple code is using [**`Enumerable#find`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) :

```
def sum_to_n?(array, n)
  !!array.find{|e| array.include?(n-e)}
end

puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 9)
puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 12)
# >> true
# >> false
```

**Update(as per @Łukasz Niemier)**

```
def sum_to_n?(array, n)
  array.any? { |num| array.include?(n - num) }
end

puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 9)
puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5], 12)
# >> true
# >> false
```

But I would go with `Enumerable#find`,as it will stop the iteration,once it will find the item,which is not the case with `Enumerable#any?`.

Comment: Why not `array.any? { |num| array.include?(n - num) }`?

Answer (score 0):

I had more luck with `.combination` and `.any?`:

```
return array.combination(2).any? {|a, b| a + b == n}
```

This will return true if anything sums together, false if not. You will need more to deal with empty arrays, though.